# Need to render Office files (doc,excel,pptx) on UI using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ms-word, frontend, aspose.words

I need to render my Office files (docx,excel,pptx) on the UI without using Google Viewer or Microsoft Document Viewer as those are using some online server calls to make those rendering possible?

But i want to just render it directly from my front end code or by using some libraries that dont use any external online api calls.

Please help.

I have tried Aspose.words library but , I think that is also making online https: calls to do the rendering of the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words is an on-premises API and can work offline: https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/product-overview/

However, if your source document contains references to external resources, Aspose.Words might do requests to access them. You can control this behavior using [IResourceLoadingCallback](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.loading/iresourceloadingcallback/).

Also, there is Cloud version of Aspose.Words API:
https://docs.aspose.cloud/words/getting-started/overview/